# what about one BufferedOutputStream wrap another BufferedOutputStream?

Tags: java, io

what about one BufferedOutputStream wrap another BufferedOutputStream?    this question is simple. but confused.
    As the following code,

```
        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(buffer);      //wrap buffer twice
        OutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);  // wrap as ObjectOutputStream
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream); //wrap back as BufferedOutputStream
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream1);
```

Comment: Do you have some context along with this question?

Answer (score 0):

What about it? Question?

If you're asking whether an inefficiency is introduced, the answer is 'no'. The code is optimised to handle that case, or rather the case where the transfer size >= the buffer size.